# Relative File Path Problem

Tags: java, portlet, zk

I am developing a portlet that is trying to read in a config file. I am developing it in an eclipse project. I currently have the config file placed inside my WEB-INF folder (which is in root/WEB-INF/), and its called config.properties. How can I access this file using relative path in my java source code? (which is in root/src/package/mysource.java)

For example,

```
File myfile = new File("WHAT DO I PUT HERE/config.properties");
```

Any help you can provide would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I would load that using the servlet context and its getResourceAsStream() method instead of a File.  Like [this](http://www.xyzws.com/Servletfaq/how-to-use-servletcontextgetresourceasstreamjavalangstring-path/18)....

Sorry, you said portlet.  You'll need [javax.portlet.PortletContext](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-api/apidocs/javax/portlet/PortletContext.html) then.

You can get the PortletContext from the [PortletSession](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-api/apidocs/javax/portlet/PortletSession.html).  You can create a PortletSession from a [PortletRequest](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-api/apidocs/javax/portlet/PortletRequest.html).

Comment: I am making a portlet for liferay, so I dont think I can use that?

Comment: Use PortletContext, then.  It also has a getResourceAsStream method.

Comment: How can I call getPortletContext()?

Comment: From the PortletSession, of course: http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-api/apidocs/javax/portlet/PortletSession.html

Comment: It's sent to you.  It's a parameter passed into the action or render request: http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a portlet, you'll probably want to use the [PortletContext](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-api/apidocs/javax/portlet/PortletContext.html).

Although there is a `getRealPath` method, I would avoid it as it is dependent on how the portal application is deployed - there is no guarantee that the resource is going to map to a file on the file system. Go instead for `getResourceAsStream` (or, if you must, `getResource`).

Comment: How do I declare a new PortletContext?

PortletContext context = ??

Comment: It is provided by the container. You can get it from the `GenericPortlet`, or the `PortletSession`, or the `PortletRequest`, or the `PortletConfig`.

Comment: Im developing my portlet in Java, based on the ZK framework. Right now, I have a class that extends from a GenericForwardComposer so Im not sure how to get those things.

Comment: @ApacheImageUser - that sort of information should be stated up front (I've tagged the question); I am not familiar with that framework.