# Liferay portlet and relative path

Tags: java, path, liferay, portlet

This question probably was answred on SO already but I didnt manage to make it work myself...

I have a Liferay Portlet and I am trying to read some config.xml file when this portlet initialize (is re-deployed). However, I cant seem to get the relative (or absolute) path to the portlet from Java... [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224072/relative-file-path-problem) was kind of close to the problem I am solving but the url does not work anymore...

When I call

```
String path = getPortletContext().getRealPath("someDirectoryExample");
```

in a method AFTER the problem was initialize, it works, but I would like to do it inside the portlet constructor (= during init phase). This, however, end with this extremely long exception streak:

```
09:43:43,905 INFO  [STDOUT] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Config is null, please ensure that your init(config) method calls super.init(config)

09:43:43,905 INFO  [STDOUT]     at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.getPortletContext(GenericPortlet.java:463)

09:43:43,905 INFO  [STDOUT]     at com.logic.PortletVisual.<init>(PortletVisual.java:23)

09:43:43,905 INFO  [STDOUT]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
...
```

It would be totally ok, if I could just put the xml file somewhere in docroot or any other directory and use relative path, but the java class did not find the file even if I copied it everywhere... (default path is bin directory of the server -  JBossAS, but I would like to keep this file in my portelt directories).

Thanks for any tips!

EDIT: Dont get confused by the exception. Everything works fine when I dont try to call the getRealPath() function in constructor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, "The Portlet Constructor" is not "=init phase", [init()](http://docs.liferay.com/portlet-api/2.0/javadocs/javax/portlet/Portlet.html#init%28javax.portlet.PortletConfig%29) is "init phase".

Further, be aware that nobody guarantees that getRealPath actually returns a meaningful value - see [its javadoc](http://docs.liferay.com/portlet-api/2.0/javadocs/javax/portlet/PortletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29). The message that you give in the exception suggests that your `init()` code should first call `super.init()` and then assume that the framework did set up the portletContext.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for making this clearer to me. However, is there a way how to access resources (like XML files) in constructor of the portlet? If so, how to do it? If not, is there some alternative? This is what troubles me the most and I havent found any tutorials on this... ALso, this exception only occurs when trying to get the path in constructor, all other things work fine!

Comment: Why is it mandatory to go through all kinds of hoops just to do it in the constructor? The lifecycle documentation clearly states that init() will be called before any other meaningful action. You're using a framework - use that framework's default mode of operation. It will make your life much easier, but more important: It will make every future maintainer's life much easier if they can just state the standard assumptions for a framework and assume they are honored.

Comment: You are right, I am quite new to all this "portlet" stuff :-) I will try to do it in the init() function. Do you know if there is some equivalent to getRealPath() that would work better for my problem?